# Practice qualifying question Analysis

Tags: real-analysis

So I am looking at old qualifying exams for an entrance program in august. I am struggling with a few of the problems and the following one in particular.

Let $f:[0,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ be continuous, and assume that $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ exists and is a finite number $L$. What can be said about

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{0}^{1} f(nx)dx?$$
Prove your answer.

I am confused as to what the goal of this exercise is and I am not sure where to begin. Any guidance woud be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried making a picture? Maybe it helps to visualize with a good example such as $f(x)=\frac{1+x}{2+x}$.

Comment: Making the substitution $u=nx$, the integral is $\int_{0}^{n} f(u)\,du$. So if $L \ne 0$, the limit definitely doesn't exist. If $L=0$, it's more complicated?

Comment: It is a good problem in analysis, related to convergence results for passing limits through integrals.  It is also one where you might "want" to use some type of Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem, but you can also prove it directly without knowing such dominated convergence theorems (the assumptions will help out for some pesky particulars). The first step is to get some intuition, what do you think the answer should be? Can you take steps to prove it?

Comment: @preferred_anon : Minor fix it would be $\frac{1}{n}\int_0^n f(u)du$.

Comment: @Michael oops, thank you!

Comment: @geoplanted : My comment on passing a limit through the integral intended to inspire you to state an intuitive guess (which then can lead to a solution).  The preemptive answer by Kavi seems to have prevented that.  Nevertheless that answer is incomplete as it does not use the assumptions (and there are obvious counter-examples if you neglect continuity and the closed domain, such as $f(x) = \frac{L(x+1)}{x}$). So part of this problem (to deal with the "pesky particulars" I mentioned) is to prove the function is bounded. This is why it is a good analysis problem.

Answer (score 3):

$|\frac 1 n \int_0 ^{n} (f(x)-L)\, dx \leq |\frac 1 n \int_0 ^{c} (f(x)-L)\, dx+|\frac 1 n \int_c ^{n} (f(x)-L)\, dx$. First choose $c$ such that $|f(x)-L| <\epsilon$ for $x >c$. Then the second term is less than $\epsilon$. Now let $n \to \infty$ in the first term. Thus $\frac 1 n \int_0 ^{n} (f(x)-L)\, dx \to 0$. This shows the given limit is $L$ (because $\int_0^{1} f(nx)\, dx =\frac 1 n \int_0 ^{n} f(x)\, dx$).

Comment: This neglects an important continuity assumption (on the domain of $f$)  that is given in the problem and that deals with a "pesky particular" as I mentioned in my comment above.  So, part of this problem is to prove something about $f$ based on the given assumptions (after which an argument such as the above, or other similar arguments, or Lebesgue Dominated Convergence, will work).